# Combining Couplings of Random Variables

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, coupling

Given $n$, let $(A_i){i\le n}, (B_i)_{i\le n}$ be sequences of distinct random variables, where $(B_i)_i$ is an independent process. 
For each $i$, I have a coupling of $A_i,B_i$ with some desired feature (e.g., $A_i$ divides $B_i$).

How can I construct a probability space that contains all of these couplings? That is, how can I construct a probability space so that $A_i$ divides $B_i$ for all $i\le n$?

One idea is to consider the product measure, but how can we be certain that the desired features (division) will carry over into the product space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer to the 1st version of the question

In general, this may not be possible.

Say, $n=2$.

- Let $A_1$ be a $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$ Bernoulli variables over $\{-1,1\}$ and $A_2:=A_1$.
- Let $B_1$ be a $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$ Bernoulli variables over $\{-1,1\}$ and $B_2:=-B_1$.

Then there is an obvious coupling $(A'_1,B'_1)$ of $A_1$ and $B_1$ in which $A'_1=B'_1$, and likewise there is a coupling $(A'_2,B'_2)$ of $A_2$ and $B_2$ in which $A'_2=B'_2$.  But clearly, there is no coupling $((A''_1,A''_2),(B''_1,B''_2))$ of $(A_1,A_2)$ and $(B_1,B_2)$ such that $A''_1=B''_1$ and $A''_2=B''_2$.

If you are particularly interested in the property "$A_i$ divides $B_i$", still this may not be possible.

- Let $A_1$ be a $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$ Bernoulli variables over $\{1,2\}$ and $A_2:=A_1$.
- Let $B_1$ be a $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$ Bernoulli variables over $\{1,2\}$ and $B_2:=3-B_1$.

Note that in a coupling $(A'_1,B'_1)$ of $A_1$ and $B_1$, we have $A'_1|B'_1$ almost surely if and only if $A'_1=B'_1$ almost surely.
Now, there is a coupling $(A'_1,B'_1)$ of $A_1$ and $B_1$ in which $A'_1|B'_1$ (choose $A'_1=B'_1$), and there is a coupling $(A'_2,B'_2)$ of $A_2$ and $B_2$ in which $A'_2|B'_2$ (again, choose $A'_2=B'_2$), but there is no coupling $((A''_1,A''_2),(B''_1,B''_2))$ of $(A_1,A_2)$ and $(B_1,B_2)$ such that $A''_1|B''_1$ and $A''_2|B''_2$.

### Answer to the 2nd version of the question

The answer to your modified answer is still "no".  The "equalities" in my example above are meant to exaggerate what can go wrong.  The same problem persists.  Namely, suppose $A_1,A_2$ are "strongly dependent", for instance, $A_1=A_2$ with probability close to $1$.

- Let $(A'_1,B'_1)$ be a coupling of $A_1$ and $B_1$ such that $A_1=B_1$ with probability close to $1$,
- Let $(A'_2,B'_2)$ be a coupling of $A_2$ and $B_2$ such that $A_2=B_2$ with probability close to $1$,

Then, if you were able to construct a coupling $((A''_1,A''_2),(B''_1,B''_2))$ of $(A_1,A_2)$ and $(B_1,B_2)$ such that $(A''_1,B''_1)$ and $(A''_2,B''_2)$ have the same properties (i.e., $A''_1=B''_1$ with probability close to $1$ and $A''_2=B''_2$ with probability close to $1$), then you would necessarily get $B''_1=B''_2$ with probability close to $1$, contradicting with the independence of $B_1$ and $B_2$.

Comment: What if the sequences are of distinct random variables and the $B_i$ are independent? Are there any techniques to construct a probability space with the desired features?

Comment: My random variables are "distinct".  They just happen to coincide almost surely.

Comment: I mean $A_i$ are distinct (for each $i$) and same for $B_i$. I've edited the description of these sequences.

Comment: Thanks for the counterexamples. I find this a bit counterintuitive. Although the desired features don't hold in your probability space, I feel that they should be implied by the distributions of the marginals. That is, $P((A_1'', B_1'')=(a,b))=0$ when $a$ doesn't divide $b$, and $P((A_2'',B_2'')=(a,b))=0$ when $a$ doesn't divide $b$. So I would expect $A_1'' \vert B_1''$ and $A_2'' \vert B_2''$ almost surely.